# Merging PDF's in multiple locations with pdftk

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, merge, pdftk

I'm trying to merge multiple PDF's calling pdftk from a batch or VBS script file.
The issue is that the PDF's are all located in subfolders within a common parent directory. Example: *parent folder > subfolder1, subfolder2, subfolder3*, where the script/BAT file is located in *parent folder* and each *subfolder* contains a PDF.

pdftk is called as follows: *pdftk.exe* **.pdf cat output OutputFile.pdf*

This will merge only the PDF's in the current directory though, and not in the subfolders.
Is there a way to do one of the following:

1. Use the VBS/BAT file to copy all PDF's in the subfolders to another directory, and not error-out if some of the subfolders are empty
2. Have pdftk look through the subfolders to select the PDF's to merge

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Wscript.Echo "begin."
Dim pdffiles
pdffiles=""
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSuperFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(WScript.Arguments(0))
Call ShowSubfolders (objSuperFolder)

Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "pdftk.exe", pdffiles & " output combined.pdf", "", "runas", 1

Wscript.Echo "end."

WScript.Quit 0

Sub ShowSubFolders(fFolder)
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fFolder.Path)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each objFile in colFiles
        If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "PDF" Then
            pdffiles=pdffiles & " " & objFile.Name
        End If
    Next

    For Each Subfolder in fFolder.SubFolders
        ShowSubFolders(Subfolder)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. I did not test it as I found a solution using a BAT file.